# Why is this media-query style applied below its specified threshold?

Tags: css, flexbox, media-queries, elementor

I have a problem where a media query with a specified *min*-width applies its style *below* the specified threshold. This happens in both chrome and firefox. I have no idea what could be causing this.

[image: screenshot of buggy weirdness]

The code is pretty straightforward. The element is an an `<ul>` with its `display` property set to `flex`. All the media query is supposed to do is to change the `flex-direction` from its default value to `column`. It does so successfully, but at the wrong screen sizes. This is not some other style overriding my code - as the picture shows, this is the specific rule that is being applied, even though the screen is more than 60px less than the min-width. It will happen all the way down to 578 px screen-width, then the rule is no longer being applied.

In case it matters: It's a wordpress site using a very buggy theme and elementor, both of which I have no say in. My CSS code for bug-fixing and styling goes into wordpress' Theme-Customizer "Additional CSS" section.

I'm lost as to why this happens and would appreciate any input on this matter.

Comment: You may share the code linked to that problem. As of this picture, I can't tell why.

Comment: The CSS of the media query only consists of what can be seen in the picture. It's just that one line. 
The HTML is the code of a plugin on top of elementor on top of a really crappily coded theme, so I don't hink posting it would be helpful.

The question I have is one of more general understanding: What could possibly cause a browser to render a conditional style even though the condition is clearly not met?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understood the question, but if you mean that the certain css doesn't apply for smaller screens (it just applies to X-769px but not under X) maybe it's becuase you have set a style for screens under X.
you see, in elementor we have Desktop Tablet and Mobile for responsive desingns and each one if them inherits style from bigger screen. You probably have set a style for mobile devices which is different from tablet

Comment: The screenshot shows the chrome's dev tools. If the style was overruled by another one, it would be shown in a strike through front. This is not the case here - The "flex-direction: column" applies. 

But it *should* only apply for screens that are 769px *or wider*. As you can see in the top left corner, the current screen width is only 708px. The media query is in force. But it shouldn't be, since its condition is a *min*-width and that condition is not being met here. Yet, the style is applied, and I am trying to figure out why.